# In the Below Code how can i add line after every row in jquery

Tags: jquery

In the below code how can i add one line after every row in jquery.i am creating an menu dynamically by using of json.so when i get all data i populate it in my menu,but in menu all data look like simple becouse of that i cant differentiate perticuler row.so that why i have to put one horizontal line after every row.can any one help me for putting line after every row in below clde.line is after li.

```
$.each(yourJson.data, function (i) {
    var li = $('<li/></br>').on('click', function () { window.location = "HTMLPage.htm" })
        .addClass('yourCssClass')
        .attr('data-theme', 'c')
        .appendTo(list);
    var aaa = $('<a/>')
        .html(yourJson.data[i].name + " <span class='patient-list_txt2-blue'>" + yourJson.data[i].dateTime + "</span>")
        .attr('data-transition', 'slide')
        .appendTo(li);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('li').after('<hr class="line"></hr>');
```

Add it afterwards:

```
$.each(yourJson.data, function (i) {
    var li = $('<li/></br>').on('click', function () { window.location = "HTMLPage.htm" })
    .addClass('yourCssClass')
    .attr('data-theme', 'c')
    .appendTo(list);

    var aaa = $('<a/>')
    .html(yourJson.data[i].name + " <span class='patient-list_txt2-blue'>" + yourJson.data[i].dateTime + "</span>")
    .attr('data-transition', 'slide')
    .appendTo(li);
});

// After the loop
$(yourJson.data).find('li').after('<hr class="line"></hr>');
```

Comment: You probably also don't need `</br>` in line 2.

Comment: but if i not write then date is overlapping.so that i put br.

Comment: not working.can u tell me how to write this without class.is the class necessary.and i write class on my style in my html code but still  it is not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I edited my answer again, try moving it down like in my example.